# I can't change the destination file

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, mp4, pytube

I can't figure out how to change the destination file in pytube while trying to download a .mp4 file.

I've tried (and failed):

```
def mp4():
    from pytube import YouTube 
    import os

        ......(non important code for the question)

    # destination to save file
    destination = "downloads"
    
    #download the file
    out_file = video.download(output_path=destination)
    
    # save the file
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    new_file = base + '.mp4'
    os.rename(out_file, new_file)
    
    # result of success
    print(yt.title + " has been successfully downloaded.")
```

It doesn't work, not because it gives an error or bug, but because it just downloads the file to no directory, instead of to the "downloads" directory.

Instead i wanted the download to be in the "downloads" folder.

replit with all code is [here](https://replit.com/@guhsdaz/Player?v=1)

Comment: A guess since I'm not familiar with the pytube API, but it would seem likely that your `destination = "downloads"` isn't correctly referencing the folder. Could you try it but replace `"downloads"` with the full path to your downloads folder (i.e. `"C:\Users\username\Downloads"`)?

Comment: I'm not a Chromebook, so I can't use that. I'm not saying for sure though since I don't know. @Shorn

Comment: try to use `Pathlib` to define your path. Or simply `/downloads`

Comment: It didn't work, any other ideas